# Check that input is composed of letters from other word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
print('abcdefg')
input('Arrange word from following letters: ')
```

I want to return True if the input consists of letters from the printed string but it doesn't have to have all of printed letters.

Comment: sort the both string, and then compare with `==`. In short, `print(sorted("abcdefg") == sorted(input())) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a perfect use case for sets especially for [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset):

```
print('abcdefg')
given_input = input('Arrange word from following letters: ')

if set(given_input).issubset('abcdefg'):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

or directly print (or return) the result of the issubset operation without `if` and `else`:

```
print(set(given_input).issubset('abcdefg'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a little like homework...

Basically you would need to do this: Store both strings in variables. e.g. `valid_chars` and `s`.
Then loop through `s` one character at a time. For each character check if it is in `valid_chars` (using the `in` operator). If any character is not found in `valid_chars` then you should return `False`. If you get to the end of the loop, return `True`.

If the `valid_chars` string is very long it would be better to first put them into a `set` but for short strings this is not necessary.